# sum nested data with swift

Tags: swift, xcode, nested

I am trying to sum nested data without success.
This is my data:

```
        {
        "BON_PK" = 34;
        "BON_EXTRA" = "100.00";
        Line = ({ "LIG_PRICE" = "40.80";},
                { "LIG_PRICE" = "40.80";})             
        },
       {
        "BON_PK" = 35;
        "BON_EXTRA" = "10.00";
        Line = ({"LIG_PRICE" = "40.80";},
                {"LIG_PRICE" = "40.80";})})
```

This is what I tried:

```
vPrice = vArr.map {$0?.Line!.map {(($0.LIG_PRICE as NSString).floatValue)}}.reduce(0, +)
```

This one is working but not the nested one:

```
vDelTotal = vArrBon.map { ($0?.BON_EXTRA!.toFloat)! }.reduce(0, +)
```

I created a 'toFloat' Function   that is not working with the nested one.
I have this error message:

> Cannot convert value of type '[Float]?' to closure result type 'Float'

Comment: You need to sum the result of the inner arrays and then sum those intermediate sums (`....map { ...map { ... }.reduce(0, +) }.reduce(0, +)`), or flatten it first then sum everything `....flatMap { ...map { ... } }.reduce(0, +)`

Comment: Perfect Alexander !!!!